# Installing SOIL

Tags: macos, installation, soil

I have a problem linking SOIL and the compiler gave this error

```
ld: library not found for -lSOIL
cland: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: i found a way that as far as i know works

Comment: when i try to use a soil function i get errors

Comment: Ignore those 2 comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All SOIL files have to be put somewhere where they can be #include d into the project. Only #include the SOIL.h file.